# Are $U_{13}$ and $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ isomorphic? Prove your answer correct.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to find a quick way to show that it is not the case.

$Ord(\Bbb{Z}_{12})=12$

$Ord(U_{13})=12\times13^{k-1}, k\in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge0}$

Since the order of the groups are not identitical (except for $k=1$), the groups are not isomorphic.

Comment: Is $U_{13}$ the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes , that is correct.

Comment: Well if $p$ is prime then $U_{p}$ is cyclic of order $p-1$. In your case one can verify that $2$ is a generator of $U_{13}$.

Comment: The order of $U_{13}$ is $12$ (since $13$ is prime), and $U_{13}$ is generated by the element $2$, for example. Now, any isomorphism from $U_{13}$ to $\mathbb Z_{12}$ will be entirely specified by where the element $2$ goes. Can you work from here?

Comment: Aston Villa, yes I can. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|\mathbb{Z}_{12}|=12$ and $|\mathbb{U}_{13}|=\phi(13)=12$ where $\phi$ denotes the Euler phi function.

Since both $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ and $\mathbb{U}_{13}$ are both cyclic and cyclic groups of same order are isomorphic, $$\mathbb{Z}_{12}\cong \mathbb{U}_{13}$$